# the purpose of induction

Tags: logic, induction, philosophy

After getting an answer (in a comment) from [peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054446/how-to-point-out-errors-in-proof-by-induction) I have a follow up question.

If, in [all horses are the same color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color) problem for example, we need to use reason, reason which is specific to the case, in order to find that "hole" between the correct base case and the correct inductive step. That "hole" where n=2 which makes the proof collapse.

So how can we verify that our hypotheses are correct and that there are no "holes"?

I mean if we proved the base case p(0) or p(1) or p((int)whatever) is true and the inductive step is true, how can be sure that there no "holes" in the hypothesis?

**Do we use induction only to prove what we know, beyond any doubt, is true?
But doesn't that contradicts the purpose of a proof?**

I know this is such a Newbie question.. but I have searched for answers for these specific questions and I could not find..

Thank you all!

Comment: I'm aware but the question there was if there is anything wrong with the induction itself in 'all horses are the same color' after hearing two people saying that there isn't, I'm now asking the real question I wanted to ask and I didn't want to so this in comments so I opened a new thread.. I hope there won't be duplicates..

Comment: I've added the tag (philosophy) because it is ultimately what this question is. The question doesn't have to be restricted to induction, it can be asked for all proofs. You can never be $100\%$ sure that a proof is right. The best you can do is convince yourself that it is right. I'm sure that there are some wrong proofs (and 'facts') which I deem correct and aren't. This happens for me and for everyone.

Comment: @GitGud That's another way to look at it.. Although there are proofs by induction that I think are considered "Totally and completely" correct and I would agree with that.. Maybe just some propositions are more problematic.. So I think the answer I got is that it's a problem and you have to do careful analysis in order to verify you hypothesis..

Comment: @git This is the reason why Hilbert wanted a formal proof that the peano axioms do not produce any contradiction, which was proven to be impossible by Gödel and Turing. But one important fact is overseen : A true claim does not become unknown because of this result. The negative proof only implies that a true claim may not be provable. And even, if the peano axioms could prove a contradiction, the true claims would keep true. A common misunderstanding in Gödel's and Turing's results is, that mathematics would collapse, it it could be shown that the peano axioms can prove a contradiction.

Comment: @Peter I'm afraid you missed my point. You can't even be sure about formal proofs. It's always possible that you and everyone who reads a certain proof misreads it or makes some kind of mistake that makes the reader judge a certain proof correct.

Comment: @Gil-Mor Considered correct? Sure. Most mathematical results are considered correct. But the same way you were tricked by the colored horses fake proof, other people can be tricked by other fake proofs. There have been proofs which were deemed correct for years before being discovered wrong.

Comment: Of course, some errors in complex proofs can be overseen for a long time. But it would go too far to doubt about the proof of the fact, that there infinite many primes or that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. They are so easy, that there is no doubt, that they are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Induction requires two ingredients: First, we must prove $p(0)$. Then, we must prove that $p(n)$ implies $p(n+1)$. If we can do this, then we are sure that there are no holes in our argument.

The problem with the proof in question is that, though we prove $p(1)$, our proof that $p(n)$ implies $p(n+1)$ is wrong. We try to prove this as as:

> Given a set of $n+1$ horses and any two horses $A$ and $B$, and notice that, by hypothesis, $A$ is the same color as every horse in the set excluding $B$ and that $B$ is the same color as every horse in the set excluding $A$.

Which is good so far - but if we then try to conclude that this implies that all the $n$ horses are the same color, we silently invoke the condition that there must be a horse $C$ other than $A$ and $B$ to which we compare each. This implies $n+1\geq 3$, so we've only proved that $p(2)$ implies $p(n)$ for all $n$ (which is clearly true; if all pairs of horses are the same color, this proof inductively and correctly proves that all horses would be).

**This isn't the statement we were supposed to prove.** We wanted $p(n)\rightarrow p(n+1)$ for *all* n. We therefore can't invoke induction - as you see, there is no way for us to get from our base case $p(1)$ to $p(2)$. We never proved that:
$$p(1)\rightarrow p(2)$$
which means induction is not applicable.

The problem is that the argument doesn't follow the rules of induction and therefore doesn't work. There is no general method to check whether a proof which is not purely symbolic works and you're right that our argument could have holes which we might not be aware of, but this applies to a proof of *anything*. If we thought our proof that $p(n)\rightarrow p(n+1)$ worked, we would have already been wrong, since $p(1)\rightarrow p(2)$ is false - and we didn't need induction to be wrong there. Rather, the issue of having holes in one's proof is an issue regardless of what technique you use.

Answer (score 1):

Classical notion of mathematical proofs is essentially finitary, namely each mathematical proof is just some finite chunk of words (just like how we write them on a paper). The most natural or standard model of arithmetic (Peano Arithmetic) is the structure of natural numbers where the distance between 2 numbers is only finite. Therefore, induction principle on natural numbers is really consistent with the finitary nature of proofs.

For example, suppose you have proofs for p(0), and any n p(n) $\rightarrow$ p(n+1), the natural way to prove p(10) per se is to prove p(1) using p(0) $\rightarrow$ p(1) and p(0) (apply modus ponens), then p(2),p(3) etc. Then concatenate those (finite) proofs to get a proof of p(10). In the process, each step we ensure there is no "hole" in it.

Now if you look at non-standard models of Peano Arithmetic:  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic, then the inducton principles become trickier as the intuition does not always lift. For example, let $M\models PA$ be nonstandard then the induction principle basically tells you that there is no definable cut, i.e. $I\subsetneq M$ and $I$ is closed downwards and closed under successor function. Hence each cut is rather complex in this case (standard natural numbers form a cut and obviously there is no first-order formula that defines it). For more on models of PA and restricted induction, Richard Kaye's book is classic.

Answer (score 0):

If the base case is correct and the implication $n\rightarrow n+1$ is correct FOR ALL
 $n$ ($\ge$ a given tresh-hold), then the induction is correct and proves the claim.

It is not always easy to see whether the implication is actually right for all $n$.
 So, in some cases, the base case should be chosen somewhat higher, although the
 "laziness" of many mathematicians leads to the fact, that the base case is mostly
 $n=0$ or $n=1$.

To check the implication needs careful analysis, as the "horse-example" shows.

Comment: It's not really laziness that leads to $n=0$ or $n=1$ being the base cases; if my inductive step works for all $n$ and the case for $n=0$ is trivial, why would I start anywhere else?

Comment: It can be easier to check the implication for higher $n$. And if it is sure that the implication is correct, it is also sure that the proof is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** prove statements inductively from which you did not know before being true or false.

You just need to make sure that there is no "hole" in your proof.
In the case of your example the problem occured because the proof of the inductive step was simply wrong.
But if you check that both p(0) and the inductive step can be proved **formally correct** then your proof will be valid and you don't need to search for "holes" afterwards.

Comment: Thank you @Tintarn what do you mean by 'the inductive step can be proved formally correct', how is this verification done?

Comment: @Gil-Mor: You need to ensure that every step you do in your proof is really correct. Intuition may not be enough as you see in your example. The safest way is probably writing everything in formal logical language but this would often be really annoying. Normally it should be enough to write down your argumentation accurately to see whether it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the principle of induction is an axiom that is selected to look after that the set of all natural numbers is the smallest possible of all candidates:

$(0\in M\wedge\forall n\in M(n\in M\implies n+1\in M))\implies \mathbb N\subseteq M$.

The axiom is *used* to prove that certain conditions $p(n)$ is true for all numbers that is elements in the defined set $\mathbb N$, by $M=\{n\in \mathbb N|p(n)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the *all horses are the same color problem* there is **no**

> "hole" [the $n=2$ case] between the correct base case and the correct inductive step.

The proof of the *inductive step* : $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$ is flawed, because it does not hold for $n=1$ [see my answer to your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054446/how-to-point-out-errors-in-proof-by-induction)].

Thus, if $P(2)$ is *false* (as it must be with a set of two horses, one brown and the other white) and $P(1)$ is *true*, we cannot conclude that : for all $n$,  $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$ is true.

Thus, the purported proof of the inductive step is **not** correct.